# "A From phone number is required” in JSON call to Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

we are trying to implement the SMS function from Twilio to our 4D application.  The phone number, SID, AuthKey and all required information I use in the tool of SOAPUI show me everything is working fine and I have received an SMS from Twilio.  However, when I try to implement using the 4D platform, I have tried to use JSON to pass the From, To and Body as a request and the response come back say "A from phone number is required"  Please see screenshot attached and I wanna know what I did wrong.

[Succeed from SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnQTr.jpg)

[Implement from 4D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWQZ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't personally know either SoapUI or 4D. But here's what I can see from your screenshots.

In SoapUI, you have the request Content-Type header set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it looks as though you are sending the body as form encoded parameters and that is why you get the correct response.

In 4D I can see you set the same header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you then send the data as JSON. [Twilio only accepts data in POST requests as form encoded key value pairs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#post). As I don't know 4D, I can't tell you exactly how to fix it, but you do need to stop JSON encoding the data and send as form data instead.

Let me know if this helps.